# Code working, but data is not getting read from database

Tags: mysql, jdbc

Am trying to edit some data in a database. In my code this is done when a button is pressed. That code is below :

```
  b1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    preparedStatement = connect
                            .prepareStatement("select * from student where clsnum='" + t1.getText() + "'");
                    rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
                    if(rs.next()) {
                       setCenter(edit(rs));
                       setBottom(addHBox());
                    }
                    else {
                        msg1.setText("Student Not Found...!");
                    }
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(EditStudent.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
```

In it, first I search whether the particular details are present in the database(using a value entered through a TextField- t1). If it is not found "Student Not Found...!" message is displayed. Otherwise the 'if' section works. The code is working fine here.

Now I will post the code that works inside the 'if' section.

```
private VBox edit(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {

    VBox vb2 = new VBox();
    vb2.setPadding(new Insets(30, 20, 25, 130));
    vb2.setSpacing(30);

    String name = null, reg = null;

    while (rs.next()) {
        name = rs.getString("name");
        cnum = rs.getString("clsnum");  // cnum is declared at the starting of class.
        reg = rs.getString("regnum");
    }

    HBox hb1 = new HBox();
    hb1.setSpacing(10);
    Label lb2 = new Label("Class Number = " + cnum + "");
    lb2.setFont(Font.font("Calibri", FontWeight.BOLD, 18));
    hb1.getChildren().addAll(lb2);

    VBox hb2 = new VBox();
    hb2.setSpacing(10);
    Label lb3 = new Label("Name (Current Name = " + name + " )");
    lb3.setFont(Font.font("Calibri", 16));
    tf1 = new TextField();
    tf1.setMaxWidth(150);
    hb2.getChildren().addAll(lb3, tf1);

    VBox hb4 = new VBox();
    hb4.setSpacing(10);
    Label lb5 = new Label("Register Number (Current Number = " + reg + " )");
    lb5.setFont(Font.font("Calibri", 16));
    tf3 = new TextField();
    tf3.setMaxWidth(150);
    hb4.getChildren().addAll(lb5, tf3);

    msg = new Text();
    msg.setFont(Font.font("Calibri", FontWeight.THIN, 18));
    msg.setFill(Color.RED);

    vb2.getChildren().addAll(hb1, hb2, hb4, msg);
    return vb2;
}
```

This section of code has the problem. I read 3 values from the database here - 'name','cnum' and 'reg'. When I display these values in a Label they are showing "null", instead of the actual values (for example, Label lb3 contains "Name (Current Name = null)" ). Label lb4 is same like lb3.

No exception is shown while running the code. What is my problem here ? How can I read the values successfully ?

Comment: Read the doc I posted for ResultSet in you last question.  Once you call next() it moves a pointer to the next result.  If you want to start over you have to call beforeFirst().  You should just use println to output data until you understand how it works.

Comment: You should separate your UI code from your data access code. That way you can test each independently. You are going to run into your code being completely unmaintainable if you carry on this way. Google "Data Access Object Pattern" or something similar and refactor your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the while loop, you've already moved the cursor to the row you want.  Calling it again will move to the next row and I assume you've only fetched 1 result.  That's why the while loop never gets executed, there is no next().

```
while (rs.next()) {//delete
    name = rs.getString("name");
    cnum = rs.getString("clsnum");  // cnum is declared at the starting of class.
    reg = rs.getString("regnum");
}//delete
```